# how to combine values from multiple columns and remove any duplicates using transact sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in sql server database having four columns for email addresses i.e. `Email1,Email2,Email3` and `Email4`. I need to create a function to return a combined  email addresses and remove any duplicate emails

(e.g. Email1 and Email3 might have same address `email@email.com` and I need to only include it once in the combined string).

I have written a function as below which does return the combined values but not sure how we can remove the duplicate emails.

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[CombineAndCommaSeparateEmails] 

(@Email1 VARCHAR(250),@Email2 VARCHAR(250),@Email3 VARCHAR(250),@Email4 VARCHAR(250))

RETURNS VARCHAR(250)

AS BEGIN

DECLARE @combinedEmails VARCHAR(1000)

Set @combinedEmails=   
concat(
Rtrim(Ltrim(Case when @EMAIL1 is not null then @EMAIL1+',' end)),
Rtrim(Ltrim(Case when @EMAIL2 is not null then @EMAIL2+',' end)),
Rtrim(Ltrim(Case when @EMAIL3 is not null then @EMAIL3+',' end)),
Rtrim(Ltrim(@EMAIL4)))


Set @combinedEmails=   case 
when RIGHT(@combinedEmails,1)=',' then substring(@combinedEmails,1,len(@combinedEmails)-1)
else @combinedEmails END    

RETURN @combinedEmails
END
```

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, you just want to combine the values in the 4 emails fields for each record and remove duplicates within each individual record (i.e. if one record has the same email address listed in multiple columns)? And your desired output is a comma-delimited string?

Comment: That's right @3N1GM4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option (if you want to keep the UDF)

```
Declare @EMail1 varchar(50) = 'some@email.com'
Declare @EMail2 varchar(50) = 'some@email.com'
Declare @EMail3 varchar(50) = 'someother@email.com'
Declare @EMail4 varchar(50) = 'some@email.com'

Select Stuff((Select Distinct ','+EMails From (values (@EMail1),(@EMail2),(@EMail3),(@EMail4) ) A (EMails) For XML Path('')),1,1,'')
```

Returns

```
some@email.com,someother@email.com
```

---

> **As the Function**

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[CombineAndCommaSeparateEmails] (@Email1 VARCHAR(250),@Email2 VARCHAR(250),@Email3 VARCHAR(250),@Email4 VARCHAR(250))

Returns varchar(250)
AS 

BEGIN
    Return (
    Select Stuff((Select Distinct ','+EMails 
                  From  (values (@EMail1)
                               ,(@EMail2)
                               ,(@EMail3)
                               ,(@EMail4) 
                         ) A (EMails) 
                   Where EMails<>''
                   For XML Path('')),1,1,'')
    )
End
```

So

```
Select [dbo].[CombineAndCommaSeparateEmails]('some@email.com','some@email.com','someother@email.com',null)
```

Returns

```
some@email.com,someother@email.com
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `OUTER APPLY` to get `DISTINCT` email and after that just concatenate them using any method:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, <other_columns>, sub.email
  FROM your_table t
  OUTER APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT email
               FROM (VALUES (t.Email1)
                           ,(t.Email2)
                           ,(t.Email3)
                           ,(t.Email4)
                     ) s(email)
             ) sub
)
SELECT id, <other_columns>, STRING_AGG(cte.email, ';') AS concatenated_email
FROM cte
GROUP BY id,<other_columns>;
```

Here I've used [`STRING_AGG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790580.aspx) which will be available from SQL Server vNext.

Answer (score 1):

With some dummy test data:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    ID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    Email1 VARCHAR(50),
    Email2 VARCHAR(50),
    Email3 VARCHAR(50),
    Email4 VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO people (ID, Name, Email1, Email2, Email3, Email4) VALUES
(1, 'John Smith', 'jsmith@gmail.com', 'johns@work.com', '', 'jsmith@gmail.com'),
(2, 'Jane Doe', 'janedoe2001@gmail.com', 'janed@business.com', '', ''),
(3, 'Roger White', 'rwhite@gmail.com', 'whitey@somewhere.com', 'rwhite@gmail.com', 'rwhite@gmail.com');
```

I'd create a CTE to return all the unique email addresses and then use `FOR XML PATH` to combine them:

```
WITH uniqueEmails (ID, Name, Email) AS
(
    SELECT ID, Name, Email1 AS Email
    FROM people
    UNION
    SELECT ID, Name, Email2 AS Email
    FROM people
    UNION
    SELECT ID, Name, Email3 AS Email
    FROM people
    UNION
    SELECT ID, Name, Email4 AS Email
    FROM people
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    e.ID,
    e.Name, 
    STUFF(
            (
                SELECT ',' + e2.Email
                FROM uniqueEmails e2
                WHERE e2.ID = e.ID
                AND ISNULL(e2.Email,'') <> ''
                GROUP BY e2.Email
                ORDER BY e2.Email
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, ''
         ) AS Emails
FROM uniqueEmails e
WHERE ISNULL(e.Email,'') <> ''
```

For the test data above, this gives the following results:

```
/-------------------------------------------------------------\
| ID |     Name    |                  Emails                  |
|----+-------------+------------------------------------------|
|  1 | John Smith  | johns@work.com,jsmith@gmail.com          |
|  2 | Jane Doe    | janed@business.com,janedoe2001@gmail.com |
|  3 | Roger White | rwhite@gmail.com,whitey@somewhere.com    |
\-------------------------------------------------------------/
```

Answer (score 0):

This firstly unpivots using CROSS APPLY with VALUES to remove duplicates, then uses XML PATH STUFF to put it back together.

```
DROP TABLE #TMP
CREATE TABLE #TMP (ID INT
                    ,Text1 VARCHAR(255)
                    ,Text2 VARCHAR(255)
                    ,Text3 VARCHAR(255)
                    ,Text4 VARCHAR(255)
                    )

INSERT INTO  #TMP VALUES
(1,'aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd')
,(2,'fff','ggg','fff','hhh')    --Row With Duplicate

;WITH cte_UP    --Remove Duplicates Using an unpivot CROSS APPLY with VALUES
    AS
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        T.ID
        ,U.Textn
    FROM
        #TMP T CROSS APPLY (VALUES (T.Text1)
                                    ,(T.Text2)
                                    ,(T.Text3)
                                    ,(T.Text4))
                                    U(Textn)
    )
--USE XML STUFF TO CONCATENATE UNIQUE VALUES
SELECT 
    ID,
    STUFF((
        SELECT ','+ cast(Textn AS NVARCHAR(255))
        FROM cte_UP b
        WHERE a.ID = b.ID
        FOR XML PATH('')
        )
,1,1,'') AS TextN
FROM cte_UP a
GROUP BY a.ID
```